# Gaussian process regression in python- read n-samples and n-Targets from file

Tags: python

According the answer here [Implementation of Gaussian Process Regression in Python y(n_samples, n_targets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166684/implementation-of-gaussian-process-regression-in-python-yn-samples-n-targets)

**Is not a duplicated question. It based on those answer and I have different issues**

I want to read my samples from .txt file, which contains 3D-coordinates for each point (6x3) and looks like:

```
30.1678, -173.569, 725.724
-44.6401, -182.179, 733.301
39.7365, -187.244, 792.871
-9.43636, -200.9, 794.027
-38.2015, -199.272, 816.198
-17.6029, -189.19, 855.988
```

And one of the my 3D (1x3) target point:

```
14.8016, -175.911, 779.752
```

If I try to read my files as follows and make a prediction:

```
xFile= io.BytesIO(open('1_xRSImageCoordinates.txt', 'rb').read().replace(b'\n', b','))
xData= np.genfromtxt(xFile, dtype= float, delimiter= ',')
print("xData= ", xData)

yFile= io.BytesIO(open('1_y1InCoordinates.txt', 'rb').read().replace(b'\n', b','))
yData= np.genfromtxt(yFile, dtype= float, delimiter= ',')
print("yData= ", yData)

gaus = GP(xData, yData, kernel, R= R)

x_guess = np.linspace(-10, 10, 400)
y_pred = np.vectorize(gaus.predict)(x_guess)

colors = ['b', 'c', 'y', 'm', 'r']
plt.scatter(xData, yData, marker='o', label=u'Observations', color= colors[1])
plt.plot(x_guess, y_pred[0], c="b" , label=u'Prediction')
plt.plot(x_guess, y_pred[0] - np.sqrt(y_pred[1]) * 3, "r:" , label=u'Confidence Interval -')
plt.plot(x_guess, y_pred[0] + np.sqrt(y_pred[1]) * 3, "r:" , label=u'Confidence Interval +')
```

Then I get

```
xData=  [  30.1678  -173.569    725.724    -44.6401  -182.179    733.301     
39.7365 -187.244    792.871     -9.43636 -200.9      794.027    -38.2015  -199.272  816.198    -17.6029  -189.19     855.988          nan]
yData=  [  14.8016 -175.911   779.752        nan]

File "C:/Users/trm/workspace/gaussianProcess/gaussianProcess.py", line 72, in predict
m_expt = (sigma_1_2.T * np.mat(self.sigma).I) * np.mat(self.y).T

File "C:\Users\trm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py", line 309, in __mul__
return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))

ValueError: shapes (1,19) and (4,1) not aligned: 19 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)
```

I don't understand why the nan variables are included in the array. I guess that I parse the file correctly. or not? why I get those Value Error at the end?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementation of Gaussian Process Regression in Python y(n\_samples, n\_targets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166684/implementation-of-gaussian-process-regression-in-python-yn-samples-n-targets)

Comment: Is not a duplicated question. It based on those answer and I have different issues

Comment: Your delimiter should probably be ', ' (comma and whitespace) instead of a single comma. Also there's no point in using BytesIO for textfiles. You will also not want to replace newlines with commas, which is what leads to the nan in the yData case.

Comment: I think it is a problem "X, Y" from a file, we could do the same with other questions and say it is another question, you have a problem reading data, check if it meets the requirements of the other question, that is, if the matrices have an adequate size.